# How to add the content of a file to javascript function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file

I would like to populate the content of an anglarjs function with the content of another file. Could be a js file, a json, txt, I don't mind.

**test.js**

```
$scope.startTest = function () {
/**
 * insert content of details-1.js
 */
}
```

**detials-1.js**

```
var fac = 3;
return fac;
```

so that the final function would look like

```
$scope.stratTest = function() {
  var fac = 3;
  return fac;
}
```

My goal is to have different test procedures depending on which test you select, and to start a specific one from the startTest function.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? The problem you're trying to solve may have a better solution.

Comment: In addition to @JonKoops comment - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: My goal is to have different test procedures depending on which test you select, and to start a specific one from the startTest function.

Comment: Write functions to do all the things you might want, and have your input file just contain a number indicating which test you want to run.

Comment: Usually javascript projects separate files by using AMD or CommonJS modules. You generally import the whole function, not the contents of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably do something like this.

**details-1.js**

```
$scope.tests.myTest = function() {
  // Insert test here
}
```

**test.js**

```
$scope.startTest = function() {
  // Loop through all tests
  for (var key in $scope.tests) {
    if ($scope.tests.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      // Execute test
      $scope.tests[key]( /* args here */ );
    }
  }

  // Or you could just execute a specific test
  $scope.tests.myTest( /* args here */ )
}
```

**Note:** `$scope.tests` should be initialized somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there's no way to access the text content of a `<script>` tag unless the script content is inline between the `<script>` tags.

You would have to use AJAX to download the script (with all the CORS constraints that go along with that) in order to access the text content, and then use `new Function()` to turn that content into a new function object, something like:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: 'myfunc.js'})
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.startTest = new Function(data);
        // function may be invoked now
    });
```

You may need to tweak parameters to ensure that the downloaded content is just treated as plain text.

Note also that the resulting function would have *no* access to any variables from its enclosing scope other than global variables.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function